# Loop through random letters without repeats

Tags: java, loops, random

For each row of JRadioButtons I've created through a loop, I'm finding it difficult to ensure that no letters are repeated for each row. I don't mind if the same letters exist on different rows though.

Any ideas?

Thanks in advance.

Below is the relevant code:

```
    //loop for making flow layout for each line of random letters
    //counter for having number of the row next to each row in order of selection
    int counter = x;
    //array of booleans 
    boolean[] responses = new boolean[x];
    for(int i = 0; i < x; i++)
    {

        //new jpanel created for every row needed for the word
        JPanel jpLine = new JPanel(new FlowLayout());

        //new jlabel made with counter number for each row
        JLabel count = new JLabel(Integer.toString(counter));
        jpLine.add(count);
        counter--;
        //random number from 0-5 generated for each row
        Random number = new Random();
        int low = 0;
        int high = 5;
        int ranNumber = number.nextInt((high - low) + low);

        //buttongroup outside loop so only one button can be pressed for each row
        ButtonGroup bg = new ButtonGroup();

        //get selected button's index in any group with bg.getSelection().getActionCommand()
        final int row = i;

        ActionListener listener = new ActionListener() 
        {
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) 
            {

                String action = e.getActionCommand();

                if (action.equals("Incorrect")) {
                    responses[row] = false;
                }
                else {
                    responses[row] = true;
                    //System.out.println("row " + row);
                    //System.out.println("btn " + action);
                }

                if(checkAnswers(responses) == true)
                {
                    correct.setText("<html><font color = 'white'>correct</font></html>");
                }

            }
        };

        //loop for making the number of letters in each row - always going to be 6 letters to choose from in each row
        for(int j = 0; j < 5; j++)
        {
            //if the random number generated for each row equals the loop
            //then new radiobutton will be created for the ith letter of the reversed
            //answer, starting from charAt 0 and going to the last character
            if(ranNumber == j)
            {
                JRadioButton answerLetter = new JRadioButton("<html><font color = 'white'>" + answerForGrid.charAt(i) + "</font></html>");

                bg.add(answerLetter);
                answerLetter.setBackground(Color.decode("#566771"));
                answerLetter.setOpaque(true);
                jpLine.add(answerLetter);

                //use setActionCommand("" + j) on each button to associate each button with its index
                answerLetter.setActionCommand("" + j);
                answerLetter.addActionListener(listener);

            }

            //ranLetter is generated randomly from the alphabet string, so random letters are
            //created for each jradiobutton
            final String alphabet = "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ";
            final int N = alphabet.length();

            Random letter = new Random();
            char ranLetter;

            while(true) 
            {
                ranLetter = alphabet.charAt(letter.nextInt(N));
                break;
            }

            JRadioButton k = new JRadioButton("<html><font color = 'white'>" + ranLetter + "</font></html>");

            bg.add(k);
            k.setBackground(Color.decode("#566771"));
            k.setOpaque(true);
            jpLine.add(k);
            k.setActionCommand("Incorrect");
            k.addActionListener(listener);


        }
        //add each row of letters (jpLine) to this loops jpanel
        jpCenterCenter.add(jpLine);


    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Use an `ArrayList<Character>` of letters you can choose from.
2. Generate a random index for the list based on the list `size()` for each row.
3. `remove` the letter as you select it from the list

For example:

```
// One possible way of creating your list
// Reset your list within each "i" loop, just before the "j" loop, 
//   or you'll never repeat letters across rows
String alphabet = "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ";
ArrayList<Character> possibleLetters = new ArrayList<Character>(alphabet.length);
for (char c : alphabet) possibleLetters.add(c);

// now select randomly "without replacement"
for (int j = 0; i < 5; j++) {
    int index = number.nextInt(possibleLetters.size());
    String letter = possibleLetters.remove(index);
}
```

You could also just do:

```
String alphabet = "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ";
ArrayList<Character> possibleLetters = new ArrayList<Character>(alphabet.length);
for (char c : alphabet) possibleLetters.add(c);
Collections.shuffle(possibleLetters); // optionally: shuffle(possibleLetters, number)

for (int j = 0; i < 5; j++) {
    String letter = possibleLetters.get(j);
}
```

If you do that you don't need to reset it each time, you can just [`shuffle`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Collections.html#shuffle(java.util.List)) it each time.

Comment: If you're going to use an `ArrayList`, you could just use `Collections.shuffle` to randomise the `List` and then just run sequentially through the list.  In fact, you could use `Collections.shuffle` for each row and maintain a single instance of the `List`...

Comment: @AndyBrown I understand what you're trying to do but I'm finding it hard to implement it into my code, since one of the JRadioButtons is chosen in a separate section of the j loop so it can be the char from the answer, and the 5 other JRadioButtons are created after with the alphabet String.

Comment: @AEkon. It sounds like you want the first method then, but before your `j` loop you know your value of `answerForGrid.charAt(i)`, so just do `possibleLetters.remove(answerForGrid.charAt(i))`, then for your answer `JRadioButton` you don't need to select a random letter (note - you may need to ensure that is a `Character`, or the list is of `String`s instead).

Comment: @AndyBrown I'm having difficulties trying to implement this still, sorry for being a nuisance, do you think you can post the relevant changed code? Thank you for all the help by the way.

Comment: @AEkon. I think if you have your random selection without duplicates working then post this last bit as a new question. Apart from anything else I just turned off my PC and I can't really help from my phone, sorry.

Comment: @AEkon. Did you ask a new question yet?

Comment: @AndyBrown I'm still trying to implement random selection without duplicates, and since I can't get the overall thing to work, there's no new question to ask yet.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/70047/discussion-between-andy-brown-and-aekon).

Answer (score 1):

You could use a combination of `List` and `Collections.shuffle` to randomise the list of available characters, for example...

```
String alphabet = "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ";
List<String> values = new ArrayList<>(Arrays.asList(alphabet.split("")));
for (int row = 0; row < 10; row++) {

    Collections.shuffle(values);
    for (int col = 0; col < 5; col++) {
        System.out.print(values.get(col));
    }
    System.out.println("");

}
```

Because, each character only appears within the `List` once, it is impossible to get duplicates, but the use of `Collections.shuffle` takes care of the randomisation process for each row.

Of course, this is reliant on the fact that you're allowed to use these libraries ;)

Answer (score -1):

without digging into you code of JRadioButtons and stuff, I would think that a random permutation is what you are locking for.